# YouTube Data API WebSocket support

Tags: java, websocket, youtube-data-api, twitch-api

I have recently been introduced to how awesome Web Sockets are. I am currently making a program that, every minute, pings the YouTube Data API and gets data from a list of channels to check if they have uploaded a new video. I am also doing a similar thing with Twitch.tv live streams. I have just started using [Twitch4J](https://twitch4j.github.io/), which uses WebSockets to get the data from Twitch. I am wondering if YouTube supports WebSockets at all or has a similar program like how [Twitch4J](https://twitch4j.github.io/) works with Twitch?

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't talked about WebSub which is supported by YouTube Data API v3 (and works) for videos feed: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Indeed it's not using WebSocket but it's similar because the server send notifications to a remote server instead of repeating (useless) requests to YouTube very regularly.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at this. My only issue, with my current understanding, is that since I am planning on hosting this project on a computer inside my home network, I would need to open a port so that the push notifications would be able to connect to the server with the callback URL. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: You are right. Indeed with a master-slave model with YouTube API where you are the slave with a TCP connection for instance, you can receive updates from the server without having to open a port. But AFAIK YouTube doesn't provide such feature. You can however make such a TCP-Webhook wrapper by yourself by renting a VPS server or something like this. If you go open-source (preferably using PhP for the callback from WebSub) I can add your feature to my [YT operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Likewise you won't have to open a port and will have exactly the feature you are looking for.